# Best way to purge multi million data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-job

I have around 10 billion system (infrastructure) data in `SQL Server` of last 5 years, and I want to purge that data incrementally on every weekend, same time other jobs also running which doing maintenance and inserting data of that particular day into `warehouse`.

The purging process will delete about 600,000 records every weekend but it will scan entire data warehouse for it to take out these 600,000 records.

Please suggest an optimal way of doing this.

Comment: Are you purging records based on their date?

Comment: This is what partitions are for (or, at least one reason to use them)

Comment: It's probably best if that table would be partitioned. Then each week a script creates a new partition for the next week, and drops the partition of an outdated week.

Comment: Yes i am purging data based on date, also tried table partioning

Answer (score 1):

Partition switching in SQL Server enables you to swap chunks of data in/out of your table pretty much instantaneously. There are numerous good tutorials, here is one: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/sql-server-table-partitioning-tutorial-videos-and-scripts/

A partition in SQL Server physically separates a table based on the partition scheme, most commonly using a date range. So swapping partitions in/out of your table is more of a logical switch than a physical switch, and therefore incredibly fast.

If you don't have SQL Server Enterprise Edition, you should make sure the field you're using to identify records to delete is indexed. With large deletes, breaking the delete up can improve performance, so perhaps you create a loop that deletes 1 day at a time, 7 times, instead of the entire week at once.

Answer (score 0):

I would take an incremental approach as mentioned in the article:

http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes

The number of records to delete per batch is configurable.  You'll want to test different sizes in a test environment to get the optimal size for your data set.

Comment: Also need to take care of log file size, if we delete records in bulk in one shot it will full transcriptional log table.

Comment: True.  How often are you taking transaction log backups?